# Can additional columns be added to an already existing index key?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have created the following table -

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE fruits;

| fruits | CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
  `id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column1` text,
  `column2` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
```

Here, I can create a `FULLTEXT` key `ft_col` spanning columns `column1` and `column2`

```
ALTER TABLE fruits
    -> ADD FULLTEXT ft_col (column1, column2);
```

My question is if I forget to include `column2` in my query and instead by mistake do -

```
ALTER TABLE fruits
    -> ADD FULLTEXT ft_col (column1);
```

So, now is there a way to add the index key `ft_col` to `column2`?

Or do I have to delete the key `ft_col` and recreate it as follows -

```
ALTER TABLE fruits
    -> DROP INDEX ft_col;
```

```
ALTER TABLE fruits
    -> ADD FULLTEXT ft_col (column1, column2);
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @user207421 I don't know the syntax how to try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2-Alter syntax looks good (without `->`).  This should also work:

```
ALTER TABLE fruits
   DROP INDEX ft_col,
   ADD FULLTEXT ft_col (column1, column2);
```

You cannot do, as the title suggests, "add a column to an existing index".

There terms "index" and "key" are mostly interchangeable.

Comment: I have copied the code from my Ubuntu terminal, in terminal `->` is auto-generated at the beginning of each line. Thank you for the answer.